# How to check another column value to be the highest to determine the latest record that occurs multiple times in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called `ro_main_table` which stores details of productions such as `serial_nr`, `pr_date_time`, `machine_nr`, `record_key` etc. I would like to get the distinct `machine_nr` and `record key` from ro_main_table where pr_date_time is in last 6 hours. For this I do:

```
select machine_nr, record_key, pr_date_time from ro_main_table where pr_date_time >= SYSDATE - 6/24;
```

Which gives me the table below:

| MACHINE_NR | RECORD_KEY | PR_DATE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 9809 | 17-DEC-20 04.02.35.000000000 AM |
| 55 | 9811 | 17-DEC-20 04.58.22.000000000 AM |
| 55 | 9817 | 17-DEC-20 09.17.50.000000000 AM |
| 54 | 9814 | 17-DEC-20 07.57.24.000000000 AM |
| 50 | 9818 | 17-DEC-20 09.45.22.000000000 AM |

However, as you see there might be machines which are started twice during this time (i.e. `machine_nr` occurs multiple times). If this is the case, I will choose the record which has the highest `record_key`. For example, for machine 55 it is 9817. How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. I create an inner join like this:

```
select tt.machine_nr, tt.record_key, tt.pr_date_time 
from ro_main_table tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT machine_nr, MAX(record_key) AS MaxRecordKey
    FROM ro_main_table
    GROUP BY machine_nr) groupedtt 
ON tt.machine_nr = groupedtt.machine_nr 
AND tt.record_key = groupedtt.MaxRecordKey
where pr_date_time >= SYSDATE - 6/24;
```

Comment: Instead, you can use the window function as mentioned in my answer. This query will not work if two records have the same max `pr_date_time ` for the same `machine_nr`

Answer (score 0):

select machine_nr, max(record_key), pr_date_time
from ro_main_table
where pr_date_time >= SYSDATE - 6/24
group by machine_nr;

this query should get the result you wish

Comment: I get the error >ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: select machine_nr, max(record_key), pr_date_time from ro_main_table where pr_date_time >= SYSDATE - 6/24 group by record_key; should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function as follows:

```
select * from 
(select machine_nr, record_key, pr_date_time 
       row_number() over (partition by machine_nr order by record_key desc) as rn
from ro_main_table where pr_date_time >= SYSDATE - 6/24)
where rn = 1;
```